# error: not found: value UniformGenerator

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to import the class UniformGenerator of mllib to generate random numbers.

The code is

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.UniformGenerator
val test = UniformGenerator()
```

The import works ok, but I get the following error when trying to instantiate the class:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.UniformGenerator
<console>:129: error: not found: value UniformGenerator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiation should be done with `new`:

```
val test = new UniformGenerator()
```

You can omit the `new` keyword only where a *companion object* implements an `apply()` method that returns an instance of the class (which is created automatically for case classes). Since `UniformGenerator` is neither a case class nor a class with a matching companion object - you can't instantiate it using the implicit `apply` method.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the detailed explanation.